# height depending on content in CSS in joomla

Tags: html, css, joomla

Hi I have a joomla module "Tabs GK4". In the backend you can set the module height. But I want the module height to be dependent of the content. Is that possible?

```
.gkTabContainer2 { height: 1800px; }
```

My site is [bit.ly/1g3Fd7i](http://bit.ly/1g3Fd7i)
Does somebody know how to solve this problem?

Comment: Yep, another example of how terrible Joomla's modules and extensions are. Why on EARTH do you need so much markup for such a simple problem? (not blaming you, blaming the module developer). It seems like you'll need to use javascript to detect the actual height of the content, and then use that to apply to the parent. They've set up this structure and code in the worst way possible....